# Is it possible to escape all the parameters in multiple routes at once?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a router which has multiple routes. Currently, I am escaping every parameter being passed to the method separately in the method itself.

I need to escape all the parameters which are being passed in the URL for security purpose.

```
class MyRouter extends Backbone.Router
   routes:
     "student/:id/:name"         :        "student"
     "teacher/:tid/:tname"       :        "teacher"
     "teacher/:tid/:tname/share" :        "teacher_share"

  student: (id, name) ->
    id = _.escape(id)
    name = _.escape(name)
    #do stuff

  teacher: (tid, tname) ->
    tid = _.escape(tid)
    tname = _.escape(tname)
    #do stuff

  teacher_share: (tid, tname) ->
    tid = _.escape(tid)
    tname = _.escape(tname)
    #do stuff
```

Is it possible to escape all the parameters in all the routes at once, so that I don't have to explicitly escape them in every respective method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `execute`

> [**execute**](https://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute) `router.execute(callback, args, name)`
>   This method is called internally within the router, whenever a route matches and its corresponding callback is about to be executed. Return false from execute to cancel the current transition. Override it to perform custom parsing or wrapping of your routes, for example, to parse query strings before handing them to your route callback, like so:
>
> ```
> var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
>   execute: function(callback, args, name) {
>     if (!loggedIn) {
>       goToLogin();
>       return false;
>     }
>     args.push(parseQueryString(args.pop()));
>     if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: So in my case, instead of returning false, I just need to perform the _.escape() operation on each key:value of args?

Comment: Ah yes... the login thing is just example. I guess you need to do it after `args.push(parseQueryString(args.pop()));`

Comment: Ah yes... I guess you can remove login stuff and do `_.escape` instead of `parseQueryString(args.pop());` and it should be good